# Hide an Outlet Collections object

Tags: xcode, swift, imageview

I am trying to hide multiple ImageViews.

```
@IBOutlet var closedImage: Array<UIImageView>!
```

But it says: Value of type 'Array' has no member 'hidden'

Is there a way to hidde this ImageViews?

Comment: Please show the code that is causing the error. But note that closedImage is not a UIImageView but an array of UIImageViews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `closedImage` is an array, you have to iterate over it:

```
for image in closedImage {
    image.hidden = true
}
```